# iOS App HTTP insecure call working on local tests but fails after archiving

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Two years ago I developed an iOS app which makes HTTP requests instead of HTTPS ones. I had to add the *Allow Arbitrary Loads* value in my info.plist for this to work. The app was submitted and uploaded to the App Store and was working well until these days.

Recently, I made some improvements in other sections of the app and submitted a new version. I tested it in simulator and in an iPad an everything was working well until I archived it and generated the IPA file in Xcode. Testing this file in the same device, when I use a function that calls a HTTP request, the request gets stuck and never ends.

As when testing from Xcode everything goes well, I can´t see any error. Any idea? Has something changed recently in relation whit this kind of calls?

**Update**

Found that *Archiving* uses *Release* config and my tests were made in *Debug*, I started playing with the different build settings and detected that enabling the "Testability" option in *Build Options* makes everything work again. The Xcode description for this option is:

> When this setting is activated, the product will be built with options appropriate for running automated tests, such as making private interfaces accessible to the tests. This may result in tests running slower than they would without testability enabled.

I don't understand the relation between this option and the HTTP requests... Can I upload the app with this option enabled?

Comment: Have you tried archiving the same project but undo all the improvements you had done? Is there exist the same problem? If not check your improvements.

Comment: @AchmadJP I've made some findings. Check my update.

Comment: I uploaded an app with utilises HTTP only a week ago and everything works fine so it should still be possible. I did however add both the _Allow Arbitrary Loads_ **and** added the domains my app uses under _Exception Domains_, have you done that?

Comment: @Eric Yes, I had those settings. Solved it activating "Testability" in Build Options, but I don't know why...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As no other answers are being posted, if someone comes here looking for one: I had to enable "Testability" option in *Build Options* for *Release*. For me it looks like a bug and maybe this could be corrected in future versions.